# How do I get distinct items from a list?

Tags: elm

It's not clear to me how to retrieve distinct items from a list.

I have the following code:

```
topicsFromLinks : List Link -> List Topic
topicsFromLinks links =
    links
        |> List.map (\l -> l.topics)
        |> List.concat
        |> Set.fromList
        |> Set.toList
```

Error:

> The definition of `topicsFromLinks` does not match its type
>   annotation. - The type annotation for `topicsFromLinks` says it always
>   returns:
>
> ```
> List Topic
> ```
>
> But the returned value (shown above) is a:
>
> ```
> List comparable
> ```

I expect the following lines to just work in regards to structural equality:

```
|> Set.fromList
|> Set.toList
```

Why am I receiving a List of Comparables?

How do I resolve this compilation error?

**Appendix:**

```
type alias Topic =
    { name : String, isFeatured : Bool }

type alias Link =
    {
    ...
    , topics : List Topic
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `Set`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Set):

> The values can be any comparable type. This includes Int, Float, Time, Char, String, and tuples or lists of comparable types.

You are attempting to put a `Topic` value in where only a comparable type will work.

Thankfully there is the [`elm-community/list-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra) package which exposes a [`uniqueBy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/6.1.0/List-Extra#uniqueBy) function that lets you specify your own function to turn something into a comparable.

If you want to get the distinct list of topics, matching both on the `name` and `isFeatured` fields, then you can use `toString` to serialize the value into something comparable:

```elm
import List.Extra exposing (uniqueBy)

topicsFromLinks : List Link -> List Topic
topicsFromLinks links =
    links
        |> List.map .topics
        |> List.concat
        |> uniqueBy toString
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2021, rather than using an external library and writing a clumsy toString method (since Debug.toString isn't available for production use anymore), consider using a fold:

```elm
unique : List a -> List a
unique list =
    List.foldl
        (\a uniques ->
            if List.member a uniques then
                uniques

            else
                uniques ++ [ a ]
        )
        []
        list
```